Flutter build JAVA_HOME directory path is different from the one I set in the System Environment Variables
I set a new JAVA_HOME path in the System Environment Variables, since the old one was too outdated. However when I run flutter run in the terminal, it logs this message:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_431
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              54ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
The current JAVA_HOME path is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2" (which also shows when I run java -version command in cmd).
How do I change the path Android Studio stil points to?
I tried:

Uninstalled ALL Java versions
Downloaded the needed JDK
Set the correct JAVA_HOME path in the System Environment Variables
Rebooted the system
Ran commands in cmd to check if the version is correct (it is)

What went wrong
When trying to run my current Flutter project, terminal logs that the JAVA_HOME directory is invalid (as mentioned before)

First, the ENV variables are copied upon program start. If you modify system ENV variables, each process needs to listen to the ENV update event and then update their local ENV copy. Not app programs support this. Safe way is to log off and on again after modifying ENV. And Android Studio has an own config in project settings for the  Java runtime for Gradle.

I was looking for a way of having multiple versions of the Java SDK based on certain project requirements (different projects). How can it be possible without having conflict with environment variables setup @Robert?

I rebooted the system multiple times after editing the ENV, still it didn't work.

You still have not told us where you execute the command(s) that complain about the JDK. Do you use the Android Studio integrated terminal or a different terminal?

If you already read my answer, sorry, I overlooked the note about the website I've shared.

For checking the Java version, I ran it in the Windows terminal. For the flutter run, I did it in the Android Studio terminal.

Have you tried from android directory, and run ./gradlew assembleDebug --info for debug, and ./gradlew assembleRelease --info for release build checking? Don't forget File > Invalidate Caches if you find Android Studio isn't cooperating accordingly.
